# undefined tras setear un dato previamente, y luego tomarlo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola que tal compañeros,

Tengo este problema.
No se "reasigna" el valor de una variable tras haber ejecutado una función que debería de hacerlo ( o eso pienso yo).

Type.js

```
var machine = "KVM001"
var reason = "Necesita sync"
var service
var snapshot = {
"reason" : " " +  service + " - " + machine + " - " + reason
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#title').keyup(function() {
    $('#getTitle').html($(this).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br>"));       
}); 
$("#snapshot").click(function(){
    service = $('#getService').val();
    $("#changes").autofill(snapshot);
})
});
```

La cuestión es que si yo pongo un alert, entre:

```
 $("#snapshot").click(function(){
    service = $('#getService').val();
    alert(service)
    $("#changes").autofill(snapshot);
})
```

Este me devolverá efectivamente el valor del input como tal, pero después de pulsar el botón, solo obtengo "undefined"

Comment: no tendrías que usar snapshot en su posición **reason**?

Comment: No, no le hace falta porque no es una función, si te fijas almacena datos en formato JSON.

Comment: esa función autofill, tú la definiste?

Comment: Podrias añadir el html ?

Comment: Lo publico en JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sincorchetes/spq78gkm/14/, autofill la conseguí de aquí: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creative-area/jQuery-form-autofill/master/jquery.formautofill.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema de declaraciones. Fíjate lo que sucede:

```js
var machine = "KVM001" // Valor: KVM001
var reason = "Necesita sync" // Valor: Necesita sync
var service // Valor: **undefined**
var snapshot = {
"reason" : " " +  service + " - " + machine + " - " + reason
} // Valor: {"reason": "undefined - KVM001 - Necesita sync"}
```

Luego, sin reasignar el valor de snapshot intentas pasarlo como argumento en el la función autofill(). Así que recibirás, de nuevo el valor cuya 'reason' es undefined.

Te sugiero que construyas dinámicamente esa string, intenta este código:

```js
var machine = "KVM001";
var reason = "Necesita sync";
var service;
var snapshot = {reason: `${service} - ${machine} - ${reason}`};

const buildSnapshot = (service, machine, reason) => ({reason: `${service} - ${machine} - ${reason}`});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#title').keyup(function() {
    $('#getTitle').html($(this).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br>"));       
  }); 
  $("#snapshot").click(function(){
    service = $('#getService').val();
    snapshot = buildSnapshot(service, machine, reason);
    
    console.log(snapshot); // o alert(snapshot, lo que tú prefieras, pero alert te dara [Object object])
    // $("#changes").autofill(snapshot);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="title">title Input</label>
<input id="title">

<div id="getTitle"></div>

<label for="getService">getService Input</label>
<input id="getService">

<button id="snapshot">Make Snapshot</button>

<div id="changes">Changes</div>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias @fernando-carrascosa ! Funcionó. Claro yo no lo entendía incluso probé a cambiar el valor a este objeto literal no podía hacerlo. A todo esto, ¿Qué nombre técnico tendría esta solución que me has dado?

Comment: De nada ;)
En cuanto a lo del nombre técnico, ni idea, sencillamente estoy asignando el valor antes de llamarlo. Porque si no, lo que se queda almacenado en memoria es el primer valor, que es undeifned.

Comment: Ya lo encontré, se llama objeto literal!!! Entonces haces una reasignación de los valores del propio objeto, me encanta!!!

Comment: Ah! Te referías a las string templates (plantillas de literal), estupendo, pues!